# How to link pages of website using the Sinatra framework Ruby (issue with my href)?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am new to the Sinatra framework. I forked an online project from GitHub which was initially a single page website. I added an about page that I can access at `localhost/about`.

I added a button, "About", to link the pages with a `href` tag but it doesn't work:

```html
<button class="button button1" href="/about">About</button>
```

And the Ruby:

```rb
get "/about" do
  erb :about
end
```

I could only find single page website examples or complete websites with many controllers.

Is there anything that has to be added to my Ruby controller to make the button work? (exp same as `return render_template('about.html', title='About')` for Python)

Here is [my full code on GitHub](https://github.com/francoisedumas/demo-CPT-Batch-1/tree/project_modification_francois).

Answer (score 1):

You should use an anchor tag instead of a button:

```
<a class="button button1" href="/about">About</a>
```

This way you can provide the relative path of the page you want to link to.

If you want to use a button tag, you will need to specify the action on click:

```
<button class="button button1" onclick="location.href='https://www.google.com'" type='button'>About</button>
```

Buttons are usually used with forms with a submit function though.

Your route in the controller looks good!

Best